# RoR direct sql condition in .where

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

**What i have:**

A conditional sql request with `.where`

```
.where(:users => {:articles => {...}, :settings => {...}, ...})
```

**What i need:**

An additional condition, so the `id` of `:users` is not equal to `@user.id`

**What i tried:**

```
.where(:users => {['id != ?', @user.id], :articles => {...}, :settings => {...}, ...})
```

**What the problem is:**

syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What you might try:**

```
.where(:users => {:articles => {...}, :settings => {...}, ...}).where('users.id != ?', @user.id)
```

Comment: Looks a bit unclean, but works; this won't create an additional query?

Comment: No they just append additional clauses in the same SQL

Answer (score 1):

I have a Fact model that belongs_to Place and this works:

```
Fact.includes(:place).where("places.id != 5")
```

Answer (score 1):

The whole syntax can be made better

```
@users = User.scoped
if you_have_conditions_on_articles
  @users = @users.join(:articles).where(...conditions_on_article...)
end
if you_have_conditions_on_settings
  @users = @users.join(:settings).where(...conditions_on_settings...)
end
if you_need_to_exclude_user
  @users = @users.where('id != ?', @user.id)
end

@users
```

This will create a correct query, and you can avoid adding conditions when not necessary.

The query won't be executed until you loop over it (so if the query is not used in any view, it won't be executed at all).